# CSS file not working in Django

Tags: python, html, css, django

I am making a blog in Django, and when I try to add CSS to my HTML files nothing changes. The CSS file is not working.
Here is my code:

#### Urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from .feeds import LatestPostsFeed


urlpatterns = [
# Post views
url(r'^$', views.post_list, name='post_list'),
url(r'^tag/(?P<tag_slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.post_list, name='post_list_by_tag'),
#url(r'^$', views.PostListView.as_view(), name='post_list'),
url(r'^(?P<year>\d{4})/(?P<month>\d{2})/(?P<day>\d{2})/(?P<post>[-\w]+)/$',
    views.post_detail,
    name='post_detail'),
url(r'^(?P<post_id>\d+)/share/$', views.post_share, name='post_share'),
url(r'^feed/$', LatestPostsFeed(), name='post_feed'),
url(r'^search/$', views.post_search, name='post_search'),
]
```

#### Projects url.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin
from django.contrib.sitemaps.views import sitemap
from blog.sitemaps import PostSitemap
from django.contrib.staticfiles.urls import staticfiles_urlpatterns


sitemaps = {
'posts': PostSitemap,
}

urlpatterns = [
url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls', namespace='blog', app_name='blog')),
url(r'^sitemap\.xml$',
    sitemap,
    {'sitemaps': sitemaps},
    name='django.contrib.sitemaps.views.sitemap'),
]

urlpatterns += staticfiles_urlpatterns()
```

#### settings.py static_url:

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include the below line in the HTML file.

The first line `{% load static %}` in html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="static '<css file path>'" type="text/css" media="screen" >
```

And execute

```
$ python manage.py collectstatic
```